# How to show menu selected a different style than others for a dynamically created ul li menu

Tags: php, menu

In my php project i have a dynamic menu, ie menu changes based on the logged in users ... the menu itema are fetched from db. Now i want to show the selected menu in a different style... ie if i click on user manager, the menu user _manager should be highlighted..also fo create_user and modify_user this should be highlighted...

```
    <ul>
<li>
<a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="user_manager.php">User manager</a>
</li>
<<li>
<a href="category.php">Category</a>
</li>

</ul>
```

How can i implement this.. Any help will be appreciated....:)-

Answer (score 0):

simple way, your css have user-group naming styles.

```
<style>
.admin{}
.manager{}
.user{}
</style>
```

and using PHP to echo the user group in your menu

```
<ul class="<?=$_SESSION['user_group']?>">
<? if($_SESSION['user_group']=='admin'){ ?><li><a href'#'>Create User</a></li><? } ?>
<li><a href='#'>Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you create your menu? Obviously, you have at least 3 php files. Depending on the which is being executed, you can choose to add a class to a li item.
For example something like that:

```
<?php
$menuHTML = '<ul>';
foreach($menu as $menuItem) {
      if($menuItem == $fileName) $menuHTML .= '<li class="highlight">...etc...</li>';
      else $menuHTML .= '<li>...etc...</li>';
}
$menuHTML .= '</ul>';
?>
```

To get the $fileName, have a look on [**FILE**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) or [$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)